# How do you import a user module in D3?

Tags: d3.js

Maybe i am really thick, but i am going through this example code

https://observablehq.com/@sw1227/reusable-2d-array-image-function

and i am trying to import the module mentioned at the top like so

```
import {imshow} from "@sw1227/reusable-2d-array-image-function";
```

I only get this syntax error and i dont know what i am doing wrong. Can't find anything helpful on the web.

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token '{'. import call expects exactly one argument.
```

When i remove the curly brackets it just gives another error

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier 'imshow'. import call expects exactly one argument.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Import statement is not allowed in default Vanilla JS, you should import your main JS file as  on your HTML
Also, '@sw1227/reusable-2d-array-image-function' is a non-npm package, so I suggest you to download the source code and try to import it manually

If you're using NodeJS you can also configure Babel easily for using **import** statement and configure this package on your **package.json** for easily access to it. Then, you could configure webpack and easily serve your HTML file with this module implemented via Node